# Dymo Label Printer doesn't work anymore for me in c#

Tags: c#, dymo

i hope someone can help me out.

i was using dymo.label from nuget but i changed it to the dymoSDK but it doenst work anymore. I got an application programed with c# with windows forms

the old code was

```
                DymoAddIn.Open("c:\\reffile\\files\\output\\artikel.label");
                DymoLabels.SetField("pieces", "store:  " + some + "  " + some2);
                DymoAddIn.StartPrintJob();
                DymoAddIn.Print2(1, false, 2);
                DymoAddIn.EndPrintJob();
```

can someone help me out with this problem?
how to start printing ? how to change my label?

i'm using

```
using DymoSDK.Implementations;
using DymoSDK.Interfaces;
```

Comment: What type is DymoLabels in your example?

Comment: What .net are you running?

Comment: .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: 89 x 36 mm labels ( big adres)

Comment: What happend if you run your current code?

Comment: [Why "it doesn't work" is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I imagine that you either use source control, created a backup of your code prior to making the changes, or documented the changes such that you can undo them. If you had a working version why not use that? The changes you made aren't exactly clear, but it seems that you may have switched the library that you're using.